# Why does Hunter B-15 say "Boots on the ground" at the end of Loki 1x6?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki-2021

At the end of *Loki* Season 1, Episode 6, when Loki is talking to Hunter B-15 and Mobius, Mobius asks Loki who he is. Shortly after, Hunter B-15 says

> "Boots on the ground, archives, now,"

Why does she say this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To put '*boots on the ground*' is an expression that means "[send troops [to a place]](https://www.bbc.com/news/blogs-magazine-monitor-29413429)".

She's basically calling for backup to the archive room, potentially to contain the threat that Loki poses (given that as far as she's concerned he's gibbering like a madman), but also because he's talking about some kind of big bad wolf that might be following him.

Answer (score 6):

### It's a Metonymic literary device

The term for this is [Metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy):

> a figure of speech in which a thing or concept is referred to by the name of something closely associated with that thing or concept.

In particular, the 'thing or concept' in question are troops, to whom the *boots* they wear, are the thing that's closely related.

Specifically, this use is an example of [Synecdoche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche):

> A synecdoche is a class of metonymy, often by means of either mentioning a part for the whole or conversely the whole for one of its parts. Examples from common English expressions include *suits* for *businessmen*, *wheels* for *car*, and *boots* for *soldiers*.

It's even a known [idiom](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/boots-on-the-ground).

The [transcript](https://tvshowtranscripts.ourboard.org/viewtopic.php?f=988&t=44975) supports this:

> Man: Copy. Reporting to the armory, sir.
> [...]
> And they're all set on war. We need to prepare.
> [...]
> Boots on the ground, archives, now

Both *Armory*, and *War* should highlight to the viewer that we talking a military context.

Comment: Aren't the Hunters effectively the TVA's troops? They're dressed and act in a very military fashion, therefore, there doesn't seem to be much in the way of a metaphor when referring to or treating them as _troops_. More of a literal term, no?

Comment: @FreeMan I haven't seen the show, but I'm familiar with the literary/linguistic device.

Comment: In that case, it's an _excellent_ description of the term, and there wasn't any metaphor involved. ;)